I want to know why my rig legs jump when they are attached to a circle curve via a follow path constraint
when assigned to the "walking path", a circle curve, the rigging on the legs doesn't stay put. I am following a video, they are meant to follow the set path remotely from their original position  rather than directly by being on the path. In the video they don't move from their original position when the target is chosen in the bone constraint area. I'm new to blender and I don't know what might be causing this to happen.
I have added a timestamp for the video when he adds the bone constraint,
https://youtu.be/ktXD_WRMY8E?t=2102


The experts who hang out on this site (higher rating than me) will tell you how they disdain links to external videos.   The video (nor your screenshot) doesn't display the axes which may be (for whatever reason) different between the two (forward and up axis for the constraint).  I would try various combinations to see the affects.   Otherwise, perhaps delete all other armatures and also the mesh on the armature of interest (minimize file size) and share with blend-exchange

Is your circle-curve positions at xyz=0,0,0 ?

Hello could you please share your file?

Hello.SirGent, welcome to BSE. This one will be much easier to debug with a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.. there's too much guesswork, otherwise. Thanks

Maybe apply the scale and rotation of your curve and armature, also in the Follow Path constraint make sure that the Forward Axis is X, at last select the vertex that is supposed to be the first one of the path, put it at the center of the scene, and to make sure that this is the first one, enable the Bsurfaces addon and in the N panel > Edit > Bsurfaces > Set First Points:

